# Profile multi process infinite loop with perf

Tags: c, profiling, perf

I want to profile a program which is basically an infinite loop with two process.
I normally profile my programs with

```
perf record -a --call-graph dwarf <executable> <options>
```

When I try to profile my executable like this, I have to hit  `Ctrl+C`  to stop my program. But what happens is, perf gets stop but not my program. After perf stops my program no longer responds to  `Ctrl+C` and I get to kill it with its pid. My executable also requires sudo privileges.
I also tried

```
perf record -a --call-graph -p $(pidof myprogram)
```

but this only gives system calls.

How can I get a call graph in this situation.

Comment: re: needing sudo:  Do you have `perf_event_paranoid` set correctly to not require root? [Run perf without root-rights](https://superuser.com/q/980632).  Or are you saying you need `sudo` for the program you're profiling for *other* reasons?

Comment: @PeterCordes I need sudo for the program I'm profiling for other reasons. To read iptables to be spesific. But I also have not set the `perf_event_paranoid` I'm doing it right now, thanks.